# What is the radius $R$ equal to?

Tags: geometry

Let the triangle $\triangle ABC$ have sides $a,b,c$ and be inscribed in a circle with radius $R$. If $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ The radius of the circle can be expressed as

a) $$R=\frac{\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}}{4abc}$$

b) $$R=\frac{4\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}}{abc}$$

c) $$R=\frac{abc}{4\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}}$$

d) $$R=\frac{4abc}{\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}}$$

---

So clearly Heron's formula is being used here. I know that the radical is an expression of the area of the triangle. Let's denote $A_T=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$ and solve for it in all four cases:

a) $A_T=4Rabc$

b) $A_T=\frac{Rabc}{4}$

c) $A_T=\frac{abc}{4R}$

d) $A_T=\frac{4abc}{R}$

None of the RHS's even closely resembles to the area of the triangle of the form $A=\frac{base \cdot height}{2}.$ How should I do this? Keep in mind that this is from a test where one is to have about 3 minutes per question, so no complicated solution should be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Disguising a formula memorization as a trig problem is the oldest trick in the book. You have to know the formula $R=\frac{abc}{4A}$, or derive it in this fashion:

$\frac{abc}{4A}=\frac{abc}{2bc\sin A}=\frac{a}{2\sin A}=R$.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way might be to consider an equilateral triangle, i.e. $a = b =c$. In that case, it is easy to see that $R=a/\sqrt{3}$, and $A = \sqrt{3}a^2/4$. Consequently, $$\frac{abc}{4A} = \frac{a^3}{\sqrt{3}a^2}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}=R.$$

Also, you can easily eliminate the first two choices by noting that the area or $\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$ should contain an $a^2$ term, whereas $abc=a^3$. The radius on the other hand should be directly related to $a$. Therefore, the first two choices are incorrect.

Comment: But $a/\sqrt{3}$ is in none of the answers.

Comment: So $p=3a/2$, $p-a=p-b=p-c=a/2$, $\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}=\sqrt{3}a^2/4$. Consider (c) now. $R = \frac{a^3}{4\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that $a/\sqrt{3}$ is the correct answer? If I draw an equilateral triangle inside of a circle, I can't intuitively see how one can derive that the radius is equal to a over square root of three.

Comment: You can derive it from $R=\frac{a}{2 \sin(A)}=\frac{a}{2 \cdot \sqrt{3}/2}$.

Comment: How? What theorem do you use? Shouldn't it be possible to do it with the law of cosines? $a^2=2R^2-2R^2\cos(60)=R^2(2-1)=R^2$ so the side is obviously equal to the radius :S

Comment: $a^2=2R^2-2R^2\cos(120°)$.

Comment: @Parseval Law of Sines, https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Law_of_Sines

Comment: @MathLover- Ok, I now see how well of a thought process this is. My fatiuge must have really clouded my mind yesterday evening. Thank you very much for this smart solution!